# dropdownlist on being click should show foreign keys and the primary key in new table

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Τhat holds values in the database and when i click the button it should show me the product name, product id and the order id from another table.

```
<html>
<body>
<select nam`enter code here`e="difficulty">
    <option type`enter code here`="text" id="easy" value="easy">easy</option>
    <option type="text" id="com`enter code here`fortable" value="comfortable">comfortable</option>
    <option type="text" id="hard" value="hard">hard</option>
    <option type="text" id="veryhard" value="veryhard">very hard</option>
    <option type="text" id="hardest" value="hardest">Hardest ride in the world!</option>
</select>

</body></html>
```

Comment: It is unclear what the end result should look like. Can you provide an illustration? What have you tried already?

Comment: sorry about that